# How to prevent my dll from running when a certain process isn't active

Tags: c++, dll, dll-injection

So I want to make my dll only be injectable by my injector and I figured that a good way to do that is by only letting my dll be able to open when the injector is running. But I have no Idea how to do that.

Comment: you can enumerate running process from system and check that if certain process is running then inject your dll.

Comment: Can I do that in the dll because I want to check in the dll if the injector is running and if yes then be able to inject

Comment: yes, offourse it's possible in dll

Comment: No, this is not a good way to do this. There is no good way to do this. You cannot reliably tell if "your" injector and "your" dll are really yours, so the question is not properly stated to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mayur mentioned in comments, your DLL can [enumerate running processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) using [`EnumProcesses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses), and get their filenames looking for a match to your injector. You can do that in your DLL's [entry point function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain) during the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` stage. If the injector is not detected, your entry point can return FALSE to abort the load.

Alternatively, a much simpler way to detect your injector is to have it create a named mutex via [`CreateMutex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw) in the global kernel namespace, and then have the DLL entry point try to access that same object via  [`OpenMutex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-openmutexw), and fail to load if the mutex does not exist.  See [Using Named Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/using-named-objects) for more details.